# The number of ways to distribute 6 books in 2 places

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the number of ways to distribute 6 different books in 2 places?

My turn:

We can put $6$ books in the first place and no books in the second or $5$ books in the first and 1 book in the second and so on, we get the total number of ways is $5\times 6! \times 2 + 2= 7202$, but I think this number includes repeated situations which have to be ignored?

Comment: For each book you can choose one of the two places where to put it. So two options for the first book, two options for the second,...

Comment: Presumably the books are distinguishable. Are you arranging the books in a given place in a particular order? If not, there is a choice of 2 places for each book, so $2^6=64$ possibilities in all. If order matters in each location, then you are effectively placing the 6 books in a particular order and placing a dividing marker at either end or between two books to separate those that go to the two places, so the number of possibilities is $7\cdot6!=7!=5040$.